# GetPosition() seems to be working incorrectly on the image where the Scale has been touched

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a few images.
I increased the scale of this to make the pixels large enough to be seen with the naked eye.
After that, the mouse movement event is used to receive the current coordinates.

The coordinate value of the next pixel is displayed even though the mouse has not moved to the next pixel. Only some images have this problem, but I don't know why.
This is my code

```
<Window x:Class="ImagePixelTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImagePixelTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1000">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox>
            <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=img}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=img}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel" MouseMove="ScrollViewer_MouseMove">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="canvasScaleTransform"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <Image x:Name="img" Source="testImg.bmp" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CurrentPosTextBlock" FontSize="40" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(img);
            var aa = Math.Truncate(pos.X);
            var bb = Math.Truncate(pos.Y);
            CurrentPosTextBlock.Text = $"{aa},{bb}";
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                canvasScaleTransform.ScaleX += 100;
                canvasScaleTransform.ScaleY = canvasScaleTransform.ScaleX;
            }
            else
            {
                canvasScaleTransform.ScaleX -= 100;
                canvasScaleTransform.ScaleY = canvasScaleTransform.ScaleX;
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfNiE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw4uc.png)

Comment: Be aware the there is a complex relation between WPF DIPs (device independent pixels), which have a fixed resolution of 96 DPI and the pixels of a bitmap which can have a different resolution, depending on the DPI settings of the original bitmap file. Read the documentation of the Width/Height and PixelWidth/PixelHeight properties of the BitmapSource class. PixelWidth and Width are only the same when DpiX is 96.

Comment: You could bind the Image Width and Height like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73323687/1136211

Comment: I confirmed that some images have DPI of 77. When I modified it according to the contents of the link you gave, the coordinates where output normally.
Thanks for your help.